# Remove Column with Duplicate Values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a database with sample as below:
[image]

Data frame is generated when I load data in Python as per below code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
data_dir="D:\\userdata\\adbharga\\Desktop\\AVA\\PythonCoding\\VF-Aus\\4G Cell Graphs"
os.chdir(data_dir)
df = pd.read_csv('CA Throughput(Kbit_s) .csv',index_col=None, header=0)
```

Output:

[image]

Is there any way by which we can avoid reading duplicate columns in Pandas, or remove the duplicate columns post reading.
Pl Note: Column Name is different once data is read in Pandas, so command like df=df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()] won't work.
Actual database is very big and has many duplicate column with Dates only.

Comment: @scott boston, tried that but am not sure if mangle_dupe_cols works in a way it should work. It gives an error "Setting mangle_dupe_cols=False is not supported yet". There are many threads also ongoing which shows that this command is not working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this.

**Ignore columns when reading the data**

`pandas.read_csv` has the argument `usecols`, which accepts an integer list.

So you can try:

```
# work out required columns
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=0)
cols = [0] + list(range(1, len(df.columns), 2))

# use column integer list
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=cols)
```

**Remove columns from dataframe**

You can use similar logic with `pd.DataFrame.iloc` to remove unwanted columns.

```
# cols as defined in previous example

df = df.iloc[:, cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of do it could be to read only the first row and create a mask using `drop_duplicates()`. This we pass to the usecols without the need to specify the index beforehand. It should be failsafe.

```
m = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data),nrows=1, header=None).T.drop_duplicates().index
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), usecols=m)
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Date,Value1,Date,Value2
2018-01-01,0,2018-01-01,1
2018-01-02,0,2018-01-02,1'''

m = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data),nrows=1, header=None).T.drop_duplicates().index
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), usecols=m)

print(df)

#         Date  Value1  Value2
#0  2018-01-01       0       1
#1  2018-01-02       0       1
```

---

Another way to do it would be to remove all columns with a dot inside `.`. This should work in most cases as the dot is rarely used in column names:

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('.', regex=False)]
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Date,Value1,Date,Value2
2018-01-01,0,2018-01-01,1
2018-01-02,0,2018-01-02,1'''


df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data))
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('.', regex=False)]
print(df)

#         Date  Value1  Value2
#0  2018-01-01       0       1
#1  2018-01-02       0       1
```